# C# - Match between items in List<Items> to ItemsContainer in List<ItemsContainer>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Items and a List of ItemsContainer which is a class that holds items.

1. all the items are unique
2. every item is located in at most **one** ItemContainer
3. the ItemContainer support only: **Remove(Item)** and **Contains(Item)** methods

I would like to remove all the items in my list from all the itemContainers.

right now I'm thinking of doing something like that:

```
    List<ItemContainer> itemContainerList = ...
    List<Item> itemsList = ...

          
foreach (ItemContainer itemContainer in itemContainerList)
            {
                foreach (Item item in itemsList)
                {
                    if (itemContainer.Contains(item))
                    {
                        itemContainer.Remove(item);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Hoping to make this more efficient and elegant.

Thanks,
Aviram.

Comment: Is it possible to drop `if (itemContainer.Contains(item))` and removing -`itemContainer.Remove(item);` - without any check?

Comment: Does `itemContainer` support `RemoveRange`  (`RemoveAll`) so you can put `foreach (ItemContainer itemContainer in itemContainerList) itemContainer.RemoveRange(itemsList);`?

Comment: It depends, to an extent, how you've got the classes `Item` and `ItemContainer` defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from further information being unveiled, I've found that the constraints mean that any of the "conventionally efficient" ways of doing it aren't applicable.

Based on your constraints, I can only suggest flipping the loops:

```
foreach (Item item in itemsList)
{
    foreach (ItemContainer itemContainer in itemContainerList)
    {
        if (itemContainer.Contains(item))
        {
            itemContainer.Remove(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's still not ideal, due to the unfortunate prior existing issues of your set-up, but it'll be slightly quicker by virtue of only going through the items once.

Comment: Thanks, this would make it a bit more efficient.